# Do GAS add-on update automatically when I update it on G-Suite marketplace?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-apps-marketplace

I am currently working on an GAS Add-on, I have my google sheet with an add-on installed that allow me to display a sidebar with some function inside.

I would like to know if when I update the add-on on G-suite marketplace, do I need to reinstall my add-on on my google sheet or just refresh because it would update automatically ? And if by default I need to reinstall it, there is a way to make it update automatically ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, add-ons auto-update for all the users who installed it. As you can read in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/update-gmail-addons), in

**Update published add-on code**, step 7:

> 7. Once the deployment is saved, the new version replaces the previous one. It may take some time before the change registers for a given user.

It's also not necessary to go through the process of [verification](https://support.google.com/code/contact/oauth_app_verification) unless you are doing changes that require to update the scopes.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Last week, I had made a test and it worked well, I had refresh the page and I had the new version.
I made another test one hour ago, so I refresh but I stayed on the old version, I  had to reinstall the add'on and this time I got the new. It's not clear for me.

Comment: If you re-install the add-on you get the latest version, but for users who don't, changes take some time to propagate through servers. Some users can get it immediately, others may have to wait some hours.